# WordPress - Subcategory redirect to first child post

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have been using some code snippets I found online to get my own code. I'm using categories and subcategories on my site and the idea is to redirect visitors from subcategory page to the latest post inside of that subcategory.

First part of the code (first function) is checking if the category is actually the subcategory and if it is, it uses wp_redirect (second function).

My code works on localhost but when I'm logged in as admin it doesn't work (it conflicts with my ubermenu plugin) and if I'm not logged in, then it works just fine. I think that my code is simply obsolete or something because all the plugins are working great without my code. I would really appreciate if you guys could check it out. :)

Here it is, it is placed in functions.php of course:

```
 // Subcategory redirect to first child post
function is_subcategory($category = null) {
    if (is_category()) {
        if (null != $category){
            $cat = get_category($category);
        }else{
            $cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
        }
        if ($cat->parent == 0 ){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

add_filter('wp_head', 'is_subcategory');


function subcategory (){

if ( is_subcategory() ) {
     $category = get_the_category();
$posts =  query_posts('showposts=1&cat='.$category[0]->cat_ID);
 if(have_posts()) :
    wp_redirect(get_permalink($post->ID));
endif;
}

}
add_filter('get_header', 'subcategory');
```

Comment: Your code looks okay to me, I think you're just calling it after some output is generated. Try changing `wp-head` in your filters to `get_header`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // Subcategory redirect to first child post
function is_subcategory($category = null) {
    if (is_category()) {
        if (null != $category){
            $cat = get_category($category);
        }else{
            $cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
        }
        if ($cat->parent == 0 ){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

add_filter('wp_head', 'is_subcategory');


function subcategory (){

if ( is_subcategory() ) {
     $category = get_the_category();
$posts =  query_posts('showposts=1&cat='.$category[0]->cat_ID);
 if(have_posts()) :
    wp_redirect(get_permalink($post->ID));
endif;
}

}
add_filter('get_header', 'subcategory');
```